# How do I best give multiple arguments with the java version of flutters MethodChannel.invokeMenthod?

Tags: java, flutter

I have a flutter project (plugin) that uses some native java code as well. To communicate between dart and java I use the `MethodChannel.invokeMethod`. This works very nicely from dart for java and I can pull out the named arguments with `call.argument("name")` in java. 
The other way is, however, giving me a bit of headache as I need to pass a variable number of arguments to dart with my method call, but invokeMethod only takes "`Object`" as an argument.

I have seen it work with just the single argument like a string or int, but I cannot seem to find a good way to implement it for multiple arguments.

I would have expected that there was some sort of list object type that I could pass as an argument for invokeMethod but I have not been able to find it anywhere.

Can any of you give a hint on how to best do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter: How to call methods in Dart portion of the app, from the native platform using MethodChannel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187680/flutter-how-to-call-methods-in-dart-portion-of-the-app-from-the-native-platfor)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to pass a `Map<String, dynamic>` as the single object. (Note that each of the dynamics must be one of the [allowed data types](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#platform-channel-data-types-support-and-codecs).) This appears at the Java end as a `HashMap`. There are useful getter functions at the Java end to access the hash map members.

**Dart**

```
  static void foo(String bar, bool baz) {
    _channel.invokeMethod('foo', <String, dynamic>{
      'bar': bar,
      'baz': baz,
    });
  }
```

**Java**

```
  String bar = call.argument("bar"); // .argument returns the correct type
  boolean baz = call.argument("baz"); // for the assignment
```

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187680/flutter-how-to-call-methods-in-dart-portion-of-the-app-from-the-native-platfor/50188557#50188557) for the full outline, you can achieve the opposite direction like:

**Java**

```
  static void charlie(String alice, boolean bob) {
    HashMap<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<>();
    arguments.put("alice", alice);
    arguments.put("bob", bob);
    channel.invokeMethod("charlie", arguments);
  }
```

**Dart**

```
    String alice = methodCall.arguments['alice'];
    bool bob = methodCall.arguments['bob'];
```

Comment: Hi, That part I understand as this is what the examples show. What I am not sure about is how I achieve the same but from java to dart. I need bi-directional communication as my native code will need to do periodic "callbacks" to the upper layers (dart) of my app.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: @RichardHeap Where did the methodCall.arguments come from

Comment: @AsbahRiyas see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187680/flutter-how-to-call-methods-in-dart-portion-of-the-app-from-the-native-platfor/50188557#50188557

Comment: It should be `result.success(arguments);` on the java message to dart